# Select prior n variables to sum in SAS

Tags: select, sas, sum

I have several data files and totals within those data files that I need to re-calculate.

The variables are broken out by race/ethnicity * sex and then a total is given.

The pattern is repeated for several measures and I cannot re-structure the data files. I have to keep the structure intact.

UPDATED: For example below are the first 32 variables (and 10 rows of data) in one of the files -- Hispanic males, Hispanic females, American Indian males, American Indian females....total males, and total females for grade 8 and then grade 9.

I have over 100 of these totals to do so I want to automate the process. How can I select the 7 prior variables that end in _M or _F to sum (or something to that extent)? TIA!!!

G08_HI_M     G08_HI_F    G08_AM_M    G08_AM_F    G08_AS_M    G08_AS_F    G08_HP_M    G08_HP_F    G08_BL_M    G08_BL_F    G08_WH_M    G08_WH_F    G08_TR_M    G08_TR_F    TOT_G08_M   TOT_G08_F  G09_HI_M     G09_HI_F    G09_AM_M    G09_AM_F    G09_AS_M    G09_AS_F    G09_HP_M    G09_HP_F    G09_BL_M    G09_BL_F    G09_WH_M    G09_WH_F    G09_TR_M    G09_TR_F    TOT_G09_M   TOT_G09_F
5   2   9   6   2   3   6   9   7   4   1   4   8   4   .   .   7   11  2   13  4   2   14  10  10  13  2   11  9   5   .   .
7   1   8   10  2   4   8   0   1   2   8   3   4   5   .   .   7   13  12  13  5   15  3   2   2   13  11  15  3   15  .   .
7   8   10  9   0   4   7   9   8   0   3   10  7   1   .   .   15  9   11  9   11  9   6   7   14  9   12  8   6   14  .   .
4   8   9   0   10  6   4   3   10  9   2   5   8   2   .   .   13  2   5   13  3   14  5   15  10  15  7   11  9   6   .   .
7   6   5   1   4   5   7   4   5   1   8   3   4   4   .   .   9   7   7   2   4   8   3   4   3   10  9   8   7   7   .   .
3   1   0   2   4   10  2   10  5   9   7   1   8   8   .   .   7   9   5   7   13  6   12  13  10  6   2   13  3   12  .   .
5   7   4   1   7   9   6   8   3   1   3   2   10  4   .   .   14  12  8   5   6   2   2   5   6   4   12  6   4   5   .   .
8   9   3   2   3   10  6   5   9   10  8   1   4   5   .   .   10  2   3   8   3   15  3   14  9   14  3   12  4   12  .   .
4   3   2   6   4   1   2   5   5   6   4   5   4   1   .   .   3   14  12  12  15  10  14  11  5   8   9   14  7   15  .   .
1   10  4   2   1   3   9   8   3   3   3   0   3   1   .   .   12  9   5   7   14  9   13  9   6   14  5   7   13  13  .   .

Comment: Can you show an example of the data variables and VALUES in text format so that is can be cut and pasted into a SAS program.

Comment: @data_null_ I could not figure out how to attach a file. Please let me know if this works.I updated the original posting with an example. I was able to copy and paste it successfully. Each observation is one line. Any help you can provide would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please add some linehchanges in your data. That is night impossible to input/read.

Comment: Please consider limiting the  number of variables in the example. 5-10 variables will likely suffice. Please show the output data you would want, and show what code you have tried.

Comment: @ReneWilliams Please see my "answer" for data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the totals are interspersed between the variables that are to be summed, so we can sum "every variable since the last total that meet some criteria, such as ending in '_F'"?

It can for example be done as below. I used a simplified data set, but the totals are the sum of every variabel since the last total for each gender. I used proc contents to get the variable list. I then go down that list building a sum expression for men and one for females. When a variable named tot is encountered, a finished line of the form tot1_M=sum(var1_M,var2_M,var3_M); is outputed. These lines are collected in the macro variable totals and inserted in a data step.

If you know it's always 7 variables for men, 7 females and then a sum, so you can use simply position and not the name, there is an easier solution below.

```
data old;
    var1_M=1;
    var1_F=2;
    var2_M=3;
    var2_F=4;
    var3_M=5;
    var3_F=6;
    tot1_M=.;
    tot1_F=.;

    var4_M=7;
    var4_F=8;
    var5_M=9;
    var5_F=10;
    var6_M=11;
    var6_F=12;
    tot2_M=.;
    tot2_F=.;
run;

proc contents data=old out=contents noprint;
run;

proc sort data=contents;
    by varnum;
run;

data temp;
    set contents;
    length sumline_F sumline_M $400;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        sumline_M="sum(";
        sumline_F="sum(";
    end;
    retain sumline_M sumline_F;
    if find(name, "_M")>0 and find(name,"tot")=0 then sumline_M=cat(strip(sumline_M),strip(name), ", ");
    else if find(name, "_F")>0 and find(name,"tot")=0 then sumline_F=cat(strip(sumline_F), strip(name), ", ");
    if find(name,"tot")>0 and find(name,"_M")>0 then do;
        sumline_M=substr(sumline_M,1, length(sumline_M)-1); 
        finline=cat(strip(name), "=", strip(sumline_M),");");
        sumline_M="sum(";
    end;
    if find(name,"tot")>0 and find(name,"_F")>0 then do;
        sumline_F=substr(sumline_F,1, length(sumline_F)-1);
        finline=cat(strip(name), "=", strip(sumline_F),");");
        sumline_F="sum(";
    end;
run;

proc sql;
    select finline
    into :totals separated by " "
    from temp
    where not missing(finline);


data new;
    set old;
    &totals;
run;
```

If the order is always the same (always Male-female), you could go like this:

```
/*  Defining data. Note that _M _F are always alternating, with no variables missing*/
data old;
    var1_M=1;
    var1_F=2;
    var2_M=3;
    var2_F=4;
    var3_M=5;
    var3_F=6;
    var4_M=5;
    var4_F=6;
    var5_M=5;
    var5_F=6;
    var6_M=5;
    var6_F=6;
    var7_M=5;
    var7_F=6;
    tot1_M=.;
    tot1_F=.;

    var8_M=7;
    var8_F=8;
    var9_M=9;
    var9_F=10;
    var10_M=11;
    var10_F=12;
    var11_M=11;
    var11_F=12;
    var12_M=11;
    var12_F=12;
    var13_M=11;
    var13_F=12;
    var14_M=11;
    var14_F=12;
    tot2_M=.;
    tot2_F=.;
run;

/*  We have 7 _M and 7 _F-variables, so the first sum variable is number 15, the next 16. Adding 16 gived us the numbers of the next sum-variables*/
data totals;
    do i=15 to 200 by 16;
        output;
    end;
    do i=16 to 200 by 16;
        output;
    end;
run;

/*  Puts the index of the sum variables into a macro variable*/
proc sql;
    select i
    into :sumvars separated by " "
    from totals;

/*  Loop variables using an array. If it is a sum variable, it's the sum of the 7 last variables, skipping every other.*/
data new;
    set old;
    array vars{*} _all_;
    do i=1 to dim(vars);
        if i in (&sumvars) then do;
            vars{i}=sum(vars{i-2}, vars{i-4}, vars{i-6}, vars{i-8}, vars{i-10}, vars{i-12}, vars{i-14});
        end;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your data? You mention you can change the data structure so you will need to "program the variable names" see below where I have example of create arrays (variable lists) that groups the names for G and sex.  as implied by your TOT_: variables.

```
data G;
   input G08_HI_M G08_HI_F G08_AM_M G08_AM_F G08_AS_M G08_AS_F G08_HP_M G08_HP_F 
         G08_BL_M G08_BL_F G08_WH_M G08_WH_F G08_TR_M G08_TR_F TOT_G08_M TOT_G08_F 
         G09_HI_M G09_HI_F G09_AM_M G09_AM_F G09_AS_M G09_AS_F G09_HP_M G09_HP_F 
         G09_BL_M G09_BL_F G09_WH_M G09_WH_F G09_TR_M G09_TR_F TOT_G09_M TOT_G09_F;
   cards;
5 2 9 6 2 3 6 9 7 4 1 4 8 4 . . 7 11 2 13 4 2 14 10 10 13 2 11 9 5 . . 
7 1 8 10 2 4 8 0 1 2 8 3 4 5 . . 7 13 12 13 5 15 3 2 2 13 11 15 3 15 . . 
7 8 10 9 0 4 7 9 8 0 3 10 7 1 . . 15 9 11 9 11 9 6 7 14 9 12 8 6 14 . . 
4 8 9 0 10 6 4 3 10 9 2 5 8 2 . . 13 2 5 13 3 14 5 15 10 15 7 11 9 6 . . 
7 6 5 1 4 5 7 4 5 1 8 3 4 4 . . 9 7 7 2 4 8 3 4 3 10 9 8 7 7 . . 
3 1 0 2 4 10 2 10 5 9 7 1 8 8 . . 7 9 5 7 13 6 12 13 10 6 2 13 3 12 . . 
5 7 4 1 7 9 6 8 3 1 3 2 10 4 . . 14 12 8 5 6 2 2 5 6 4 12 6 4 5 . . 
8 9 3 2 3 10 6 5 9 10 8 1 4 5 . . 10 2 3 8 3 15 3 14 9 14 3 12 4 12 . . 
4 3 2 6 4 1 2 5 5 6 4 5 4 1 . . 3 14 12 12 15 10 14 11 5 8 9 14 7 15 . . 
1 10 4 2 1 3 9 8 3 3 3 0 3 1 . . 12 9 5 7 14 9 13 9 6 14 5 7 13 13 . .
;;;;
   run;
```

You can do something like this to create some array that can be used in SAS statistics functions.

```
proc transpose data=g(obs=0 drop=tot_:) out=gnames;
   var _all_;
   run;
data gnames;
   set gnames;
   g = input(substrn(_name_,2,3),2.);
   length race $2; race=scan(_name_,2,'_');
   length sex  $1; sex =scan(_name_,3,'_');
   run;
proc sort;
   by g sex;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data _null_;
   set gnames;
   by g sex;
   if first.sex then put +3 'Array G' g z2. sex $1. '[*] ' @;
   put _name_ @;
   if last.sex then put ';';
   run;

405  data _null_;
406     set gnames;
407     by g sex;
408     if first.sex then put +3 'Array G' g z2. sex $1. '[*] ' @;
409     put _name_ @;
410     if last.sex then put ';';
411     run;

   Array G08F[*] G08_HI_F G08_AM_F G08_AS_F G08_HP_F G08_BL_F G08_WH_F G08_TR_F ;
   Array G08M[*] G08_HI_M G08_AM_M G08_AS_M G08_HP_M G08_BL_M G08_WH_M G08_TR_M ;
   Array G09F[*] G09_HI_F G09_AM_F G09_AS_F G09_HP_F G09_BL_F G09_WH_F G09_TR_F ;
   Array G09M[*] G09_HI_M G09_AM_M G09_AS_M G09_HP_M G09_BL_M G09_WH_M G09_TR_M ;
```